# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') Can't seem to find a problem with the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

[This is what I see on my localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPUSm.pngstrong)

Here's my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from './axios'
import './Row.css'

const base_url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/"

function Row({ title, fetchUrl }) {
    
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData(){
            const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
            setMovies(request.data.results);
            return request;
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [fetchUrl])

    // console.log(movies)

    return (
        <div>
        <div className="row">
            <h2>{title}</h2>

            <div className="row__posters">                
                {movies.map(movie => 
                    (<img src={`${base_url}${movie.poster_path}`} alt={movie.name} />)
                )}
            </div>            
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Row
```

I can't seem to find the problem witht the function because the results in the data that i request from the api are certainly not undefined.

**Edit**.

For reference I've also added my console here so you can see it returning the request in the log but the error persists.

[Error in console view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/464yD.jpg)

I can see it working for a second when I reload the page and boom, it's gone and the error is up

Comment: can you debug `request` and check its value?

Comment: Well under Scope->Local     this: undefined
request: object

Comment: Maybe, your fetch URL is wrong, so you're not hitting the API.

Comment: when I console.log(request) its there

Comment: Maybe you should hide your api_key in the console dump screenshot ?

Comment: I really should

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined in your console twice after displaying the request content.

Also you should place a console.log just after (or before) the line

```
const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
```

useEffect() is called after the first render() is executed, so you surely start with a null value. And the line `movies.map(...)` fails.

Add a line before your return() with this code:

```
console.log("movies: ", movies)
if( !movies )
  return (<span>loading...</span>)

//... return dom content
```

You will maybe see (if your server response is slow enough) the 'loading...' screen message flushing before you get to your data screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [the optional chaining operator (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and see what happens.

I wanted to write this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: tried it, didn't work

Answer (score -2):

This kind of error occur when you go for accessing a property of an object which is also undefined. Like this example `let val = undefined; val.map(v => console.log())` this will return same error you get in. here I go for map a variable which value is undefined. Similarly somehow your movies got assigned undefined and then go for map returns that error. So it seems you are not properly assigning response object to movies you are assigning undefined value to movies so please check results before assigning it to movies.

```
const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
if(request.data && request.data.results){
     setMovies(request.data.results);
}
```

make sure `request.data.results` is a list of object not undefined and check your movies has no falsy values before apply map operation to it to avoid error

```
{movies? movies.map(): `<p>Loading</p>}
```

You can check request.data by consoling `console.log(request.data)` if it returns list of object then try `setMovies(request.data)`.
Follow this blog
[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined In JavaScript](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/undefined-type-error-in-javascript/)
[React - Cannot read property 'map' of undefined](https://www.debuggr.io/react-map-of-undefined/)

Comment: it is perfectly fine to iterate over an empty array. And adding the index to the key defeats its purpose.

Comment: thanks for pointing my miss conception

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).